# hadoop pig: unable to load sqooped data

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, sqoop

I am sqooping a really simple mysql table (2 columns, 'key' and 'label') to hdfs. That seems to work fine, when I look at the data:

hadoop fs -cat /path/to/my/dir/part-m-00001

it looks pretty like so:

```
93aa3fxxxxxxxxxxa86cef  somelabel
84be7cxxxxxxxxxxaef348  anotherlabel
6a0767xxxxxxxxxx70dead  somelabel
464e9xxxxxxxxxxx5e65d5  somelabel
```

However, when I want to load that data with Pig

```
apps = load '/path/to/my/dir/' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (app_key: chararray, label: chararray);
```

And the do "illustrate apps;" I get the below error:

### Pig Stack Trace

ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. ExecException : Unable to setup the load function.

java.io.IOException: ExecException : Unable to setup the load function.
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.getExamples(PigServer.java:1204)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processIllustrate(GruntParser.java:725)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.Illustrate(PigScriptParser.java:591)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:306)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:189)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:165)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:490)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:186)

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, stupid mistake on my part, the path to the data was incorrect.

Leaving this question and answer up in case anybody else encounters this not very informative error message, and because I stand by my stupidity ;)